# Downvoting all other answers to have your favorite one rise up

Tags: discussion, downvote-reason, tactical-downvoting

I believe downvoting is a personal preference and it should be used as one prefers.

Anyway I'm not sure if it's the intended usage for downvotes if, in the situation where a user has a personal preference for an answer (specifically, mind the meta effect, I'm referring to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26055754/why-must-a-method-be-declared-in-a-c-class-definition)), that user downvotes every other answer regardless of being correct or not just to give his favorite answer visibility.

Should this be considered a normal and acceptable behavior? I strongly tend to dislike it

Comment: That's called "tactical dowvoting" and it's one reason why it costs reputation to downvote an answer and, once cast, the vote is "locked in".

Comment: You can always offer a bounty with reason "reward exemplary answer" and explanation of why that answer is better to try and gather some upvotes for it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

## Nope.

Don't downvote a answer just because you like a different answer better.

Vote on a answer based on *that answer's* merit. If the answer is bad, downvote it. If the answer is good, upvote it. Even if you like a different answer better.
(You *could* only vote on the answer you like best, though)

Whatever you do, don't downvote good answers.

Comment: ... Unless it's plagiarism or off-topic or something. It isn't about the quality, it's about the usefulness.

Comment: @bjb568: I'd consider a plagiarized / off-topic answer a _"Bad answer."_

Comment: Well you say *that answer*. *That answer + context* is different. Anyway, you need to differentiate between context like "is it a jQuery answer on a vanilla question?" and "is this not the *best*?".

Comment: I'm not going to write out all corner cases where an answer might be bad. It should go without saying that _"that answer's merit"_ includes it's context.

Comment: -1 I like the other answer better. :P