# Downvotes to push up your answer - what's the policies around this?

Tags: support, downvotes

This meta question is the closest I've found but doesn't quite answer my question..  [Downvoting all other answers to have your favorite one rise up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272224/downvoting-all-other-answers-to-have-your-favorite-one-rise-up)

In this question that I answered [PayPal purchase link deprecated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197482/paypal-purchase-link-deprecated/33243800?noredirect=1#comment54299720_33243800), someone came along with a better answer that's more directly on point.  They also downvoted all the other answers when posting their own answer.

While they may think their answer is better than the others (and it very well may be), it appears that downvoting other answers may be a way to push yours to the top.  It costs to downvote, but not much.  Meanwhile, getting voted as best answer by the OP does add a lot.  The policy itself on downvotes is to not use them until after communication has been tried.

I'm not sure what I'm asking here beyond, what do you think of this situation of someone posting an answer and downvoting all the others, specifically as part of the SO policies.  I'm new enough to SO that understanding how policies are viewed is helpful to hear.

What bugged me is that I could have not bothered to answer the question.  Answering cost me.  And my answer may not have been best, but it wasn't terrible.  It had content and was a possible solution even if not the most practical or ideally quick alternative.  I also had commented to the OP and figured if they came back and said more, I might be able to use that info to better research the problem... till then this is what I knew could work for it.  So to me it's discouraging ... and I'm not sure the polices are intended to be -quite- this discouraging.  So I'm curious how policies looks to meta answerers in this area of SO.

Comment: [Problem solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33197482/paypal-purchase-link-deprecated/33243800?noredirect=1#comment54303480_33199211)?

Comment: Yes problem is almost solved on the question itself! (Waiting for CpnCrunch to reappear.)  I communciated and it worked, so far.  Yay.  However, I was debating and will leave my question here a little longer .... because it still exists for me.... what is the policy relationship to this in people's views.  If it seems like a pointless or redundant question (based on the answers) then I'll delete it.

Comment: Um, it's already gotten a downvote without a comment on why.

Comment: Comments aren't required, so that 1) the post isn't cluttered with comments that are basically just "no answer qustn" and 2) so that voting is anonymous. I don't know if there's anything else anyone can say for advice other than what you already did.

Comment: Thanks theB for your comments.  It's depressing.  Whenever I ask in meta I get a slew of negatives, without any explanation.  Of all places, I'd hope meta would be a place to educate new people, rather than make it discouraging to ask.

Comment: Don't worry about downvotes here so much. They don't affect your reputation. Voting on meta is... weird. The one on the main site? I wouldn't worry about that one either really. Although there is a typo in the first sentence of your answer, so that may be the reason. (`404 not found erro`)

Comment: don't get discouraged. Bigger problems await when you get zero comments and downvotes. At least the other guy was chatting away with you. I don't know of any requirements that downvotes work the way you describe them. That is, as a last resort. Also, you can't make blanket assumptions who the downvoter was, unless you are sitting on the page, no one else is, they occur, and another answer pops up, but even then ? We have all endured worse

Comment: also look at your answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33109076). Those 2 guys were nice. I am not sure how well it works on paypal answers, but do a little research on the effective writing styles of the top users, either in your tag or anywhere. Look at blocking of code, links to authoritative web pages, pink/peach blocks for citing material. Sometimes it just comes down to eye-candy

Comment: theB - thanks on everything.  I corrected the typo, it was from my edit after the DV.  Drew - Thanks!  True, getting answer was very nice.  I didn't assume it was him, but highly suspected. Also I don't know his motivation, but it raised the idea of it being possible "in general" and that's why I posted htere.   I posted in the question (didn't repeat here) that bit communicating first is from SO help page about downvotes here: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down

Comment: I am not a big fan of down voting on Answers unless they are just way way out there. But I only speak for me. I would first make a comment. I doubt the majority share your or my view on that. They have earned that right, and use it accordingly. That fact is confirmed by the vote counts and comment counts !  So the bottom of that url is an alternative, not a requirement

Comment: @Drew - I'm finding for the most part in SO questions that people have been nice, including about voting and I've gotten some great help.  This ques here is more generic that I realized there's opening for people to DV others to push up their own... so raised question for me - generally.  As for DVs mostly it's been any contact with meta that's been very discouraging.  Though yours and theB's comments are much appreciated.

Comment: Eye-candy... I'm not trying to write award winning thoughts, just communicate well enough to help and be helped, lol.  I'll save award winning for my still awkward parts of the website I wrote (for a non-profit).  More seriously, thanks for the ideas on that.  I have a question that went no where (but some negatives) that I've been waiting to re-post until I feel I can do a better job of writing it.

Comment: but I am coming from the angle that meta is a circus atmosphere. Allowing people to rant. Vaudeville. The DV's here are just kids gloves :) Where on s.o do you get Questions with 100 DV? None, here, well that can happen

Comment: @Drew [*cough*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3905734/how-to-send-100-000-emails-weekly)

Comment: well sure, if they lock it

Comment: I sometimes do downvote other answers, sometimes even all other answers, but that's only if I think those answers are bad, incorrect, incomplete or poorly written answers. If there is a specific reason that could be improved, I leave a comment. In some cases an answer is just a mess and I don't always leave a comment. If the answer is improved, I will often remove the downvote (if I see it), but not if the improved answer became a duplicate of another answer. In that case I think the answer should better be removed and I'd remove mine in the same situation.

Comment: But if the other answers are acceptible I won't downvote, and if they are very good I'll consider upvoting them, although sometimes I tend to wait a couple of minutes before doing so. ;-)

Comment: This looks more like a [tag:discussion] than a [tag:support] question.

Comment: If people choose to answer to the policy question, that's what I posted it for, and I'd welcome.  Meanwhile people stuck to comments and give me some ideas on how this all works... and that's helpful too.

Comment: @Drew - ah, I see what you are getting at.  :)

Comment: @GolezTrol - thanks for how you implement the policy :).  Yep, I'd wait a moment too :).

Comment: So -6 so far, without more comments.  Guess meta people are letting me know their opinion on this SO policy from the help section in an indirect way.  Lol.

Comment: @Drew - the meta voting gives the impression that along with people who try to help.. separately there are some people who hang around for the pleasure of voting on their views on how things work, or to jump on newer person's awkward questions.  It's not good for SO IMHO.  But it's also not a big deal... so onward I go!  (To read more questions and see what else I can learn about html, php, and related topics.)

Answer (score 4):

Don't assume that users downvoted your answer to push up his own.
You can't know what the reasoning behind the vote is, unless the user tells you why he voted how he did.

However, downvoting an answer with the *sole intent* to push up your own answer is not okay.
If the other answer happens to be poorly written or incomplete, though, a downvote is appropriate. Even if it pushes up your own answer.

That said, users are allowed to vote however they want. (Within certain bounds)
Communication is *not* a requirement to vote.

Comment: I didn't assume.  The question was independent of what this person didn't or did do. (Good chance that wasn't this particular person's motivation.  However, the idea crossed my mind and bothered me a lot -- enough to come and see how SO handles that concept.) The help section is very clear that communication is much preferred to voting wtihout it.  Seems like a good concept.

Comment: _Preferred_, not _required_. Regarding the assumprion: Then the title of this question is a little misleading.

Comment: @Cerbus - I didn't say "required" anywhere, I don't think.  If it's preferred, that's a strong recommendation how to do things that I would expect to be leaned towards by more experienced posters.  That's what I'm asking about.  The title is on what I was asking.  It was not misleading.  It didn't say what someone else did, only what I wanted to know about. Thanks for letting me know your thoughts on this framework and policies.

Comment: @Cerbus - so far the person hasn't come back and undone the downvote.  Till he does, the judgement can't be made anyway.  I'm assuming he/she will per their comments to me.

Comment: I said _"Communication is not a requirement"_, you replied with _"communication is much preferred"_. Exactly_, preferred. It's not mandatory. So, _"The policy itself on downvotes is to not use them until after communication has been tried."_ is incorrect.

Comment: Here's the language from the help section:  "The up-vote privilege comes first because that's what you should focus on: pushing great content to the top. Down-voting should be reserved for extreme cases. It's not meant as a substitute for communication and editing.

Instead of voting down:

    If the post is spammy or offensive, flag it.
    If the question is duplicate or off-topic, flag it for moderator attention.
    If something is wrong, please leave a comment or edit the post to correct it.
"

Comment: If you _literally_ go by the rules, sure. But practically, that's not how SO works. In fact, users are often encouraged to downvote more. Too many users downvote too little. Often enough, a downvote is just what the post needs.

Comment: Ah, so now I'm hearing the concepts that answer my question and whys and hows on downvoting policies in action.  I'd be inclined to go literally with the rules and change the rules if they aren't working.  That seems to be an SO concept.  ...but I see now what's being used based on practical implementation.  What puzzles me is still the same -- that this setup leaves an opportunity for someone to DV to push their own answers.  Does that happen (in ways that anyone with high ratings can guess is happening)?  If so, is there any concerns or discouragement of it, or issues arising from it...?

Comment: It still leaves that problem that I simply regret having taken time to answer that question.  I learning (programmer but not in this area of tools) so not much to offer very often.  But my attempt to spread wings there, didn't work out very well.  And that in turn makes the site less interesting and purely about asking questions and seeing if I can get my own thing completed.  That's not really ideal... and was part of what prompted my OP question here.  And what I was wondering about.

Comment: Sure, someone could downvote all other answers to push up his own. If that user does that on a regular basis, the system will detect that, though. In those cases, the votes can be removed.

Comment: @curls, you say you regret spending the time. Don't. You did it for a reason, or reasons. I like this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31888896) from maytham. Not that I am smart enough to understand and to upvote, but that he said he spent 3 hours on it (can be an embarrassing admission to some). Plus I like the guy. Sometimes we do research for our own benefit. Don't judge your worth or the worth of your answer by the few that stumble into it. It may be a good indication to its worth, but shed the personal response from it all.

Comment: @Cerbrus - good to know that it'd become evident.  The person on that question did come back as promised and remove the downvote.

Comment: @Drew-thanks for trying to make me feel better & point out a way to look at things. Time spent was collecting my already written code & formatting for the question, so I wasn't learning anything unfortunately.  I'm aiming for 200 points so I can comment elsewhere if desired without fuss.  So it just told me to not answer when I sort of have an answer and only do so when I know I have "a great" answer.  So it was discouraging answering but I can hope that someone else comes to the question & my answer helps them out on -their- problem (without my knowing so)...& then it'd have been worthwhile!!

Comment: And the meta question and answers has been helpful... so it all worked out!