# Should I be concerned about some downvotes?

Tags: discussion, answers, downvotes, downvote-reason

I've recently started answering more, and have received odd downvotes on accepted and upvoted answers. They all seem to have the same user posting an answer along with mine. There are also instances where the user may have downvoted all other answers for visibility on theirs, and an unupvote & downvote from a post of mine they explicitly said they upvoted, within seconds of each other. I'm not trying to suggest anything, but should I be concerned? I don't want to assume anything or cry over a few downvotes, but it's quite annoying. I understand that mods can't really do anything if it's not serial. I've tried to ask for reasoning with no luck, and I understand it's their own opinion. Should I be worried if this continues?

Comment: If there's a pattern, it's worth looking into.

Comment: It is not what you think it is.  The user does not use tactical voting as a strategy, nobody waits for 3 days, the downvotes appeared at very different times.  Having an upvote removed and getting a DV at the exact same time is odd, smells like somebody using a sock puppet.  Not so sure if it is enough of a lead for the mods, you can always flag and find out.

Comment: @HansPassant Well, to give context to the unUV and DV: They had initially DV'd when my answer had +1. I was then discussing the DV and they said "they wanted someone more authoritative to review my answer and then they would lift the DV". Once it got up to +4/-1, he lifted the DV and UVed. Then I edited something minor and then there was an unUV and DV.

Comment: Looking at your profile, I believe I can see the pattern you're suspecting, and for what it's worth I agree that it is suspicious. It's a pretty small sample size to draw a conclusion on, mind you.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Agreed. I did get dome feedback from mods and they said that there was no significant pattern. I'll just see if it continues.

Comment: @yellowantphil Even more. I am pretty sure 3 is still fine and even mods will decline a flag.

Comment: The gamified aspect of Stack Overflow actually *does* lend itself to downvoting competing answers to increase the visibility of your own, and mods/CMs (I forget exactly who) have said in the past that this is a valid strategy for gaining reputation. However, the potential for abuse happens when the same two users are answering a bunch of posts. Then it starts to look like targeting. Unfortunately, in my experience, they won't do anything if you're both competing via answers, because that could be valid voting (e.g. I didn't downvote the answers b/c of you, but because they compete w/ mine)

Comment: @TylerH Can you link to the post where it's mentioned this is a valid strategy if possible? Seems to me that it's counterproductive to what SO is for if people go about downvoting correct answers just so they can get their answer to the top (which sometimes is incorrect/not the best way).

Comment: @AndrewLi I think I read it on Meta in 2015 or so; it would take a long time to find it. But there's a problem in your comment: voting is not for technical accuracy, like you suggest. It's for usefulness. One metric of usefulness *can* be (doesn't have to be) technical correctness.

Comment: @TylerH I guess you're right, and their vote is their right. It just seems that tactically downvoting correct answers and *useful* answers isn't something that should be encouraged or validated. Does it make sense to tactically downvote an answer that others have upvoted and the OP has accepted? Thanks for the insight.

Comment: Needs the tag [tactical-downvoting] and related [Downvoting all other answers to have your favorite one rise up](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272224/).

Answer (score 29, accepted):

It sounds like what you are witnessing is tactical downvoting. It could be something else, such as [Tim losing his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/288240/165773), but that is what it sounds like to me.

Here is some sound advice from Jon Skeet on the matter (taken from the overmeta: [If you just witnessed tactical downvoting, is it a reportable offense?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/6463/178816))

> Well, there are two approaches:
>
> - Yes, you can lodge a formal complaint. Ask the moderators to contact the guy, get them to investigate the behaviour as far as they can (I don't know whether votes which are made and then deleted are retained in the database) and see what happens. Ultimately it's hard to see what the result can be - deleting the answer? Transferring votes? It would all be a bit unsatisfactory. The only benefit would be that the guy is told off and hopefully won't do it again.
> - Let it go. Move on, answer more questions, make the world a better place that way.
>
> Personally I'd go for option 2. I sympathise, but in the end it's only a bit of reputation.

That is essentially what my answer would be as well. Either use a custom flag and explain the situation with specific links to each instance you think may have had this happen, or move on... or both.

Also to note, investigating targeted voting requires someone with database access, so a flag may take some time to resolve and more than likely there will not be a response either way to indicate if you were correct or not.

Comment: It's not "only a bit of reputation". Downvotes signal that someone has found a technical inaccuracy. "False" downvotes can be harmful not only to the author's reputation (both numerical and social) but also to future readers who may be deterred from using the most appropriate solution.

Comment: Not that I don't understand what he's getting at, but my entire reputation is "only a bit of reputation" for him.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - I agree. That is why flagging the behavior is a viable solution as well. It can be very annoying to have a fresh answer downvoted when it is clearly technically accurate, especially if it ends up getting accepted by the OP.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit No, votes aren't there to reflect technical accuracy .  They're used to reflect the *usefulness* of a post, of which technical accuracy is just one component.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, okay, Mr Pedantic - "downvotes signal (**among other things**) that someone has found..." I think it's pretty clear what the spirit of the observation was. The point is that losing reputation has basically nothing to do with it.

Comment: Just an update. I *did* flag yesterday and the mod said there was no pattern, but the downvotes are continuing, now on posts from January where I have 0 score. I'm pretty sure it's just a stray, but I'd like to know your thoughts.

Comment: My thoughts? To be honest it may just be random (tim's keys scenario). The moderation team knows best, and if they say there is no pattern, then in my opinion that is trustworthy enough to believe. If you wanted to escalate you could use the "contact us" form and ensure that you get an employee only, but that will probably yield the same result as most moderators will defer flags like that to people who have sufficient access.

Comment: FWIW - As I recall, moderators can't really do much about suspected targeting downvoting, unless the user comes out and admits to it in a comment somewhere. It takes a developer to really check.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I chuckled a bit to see you calling someone Mr. Pedantic.

Comment: @AndrewLi We mostly frequent different tags, but stray downvote on a 0-scored answer from January sounds pretty fishy to me. In my experience blatantly inaccurate answers are found and downvoted pretty fast, and when somebody stumbles upon a crappy answer later, they are more likely to leave a comment. So I'm fairly certain you indeed stepped on someone's toes and they're tiptoeing around voting pattern filters.

Comment: @AndrasDeak What's curious is what has happened after I made this post. Lately I've been receiving lots of stray *upvotes*, a few I know are legitimate, and a few on **really** old posts. I'm not exactly sure what to do, but the stray on the 0-scoring one was on a low-view q/a.

Comment: @AndrewLi The newer ones are probably just the meta effect acting in your favour.

Comment: @Brian: One might argue that I am best placed to make such an observation ;)

Answer (score -3):

Here's my opinion: If there has been a down vote, it means that somebody felt the content was not worth putting up on Stack Overflow, maybe the question you put up or the answer did not make sense or the answer that you wrote had same faulty bits and pieces.

Either ways, it is nothing to fret over. A rather better idea would be to review the content written by you that got down voted and try to figure out a possible reason it may have been down voted and the next time you post content, be extra careful of what you write.

What I am trying to say is that Stack Overflow is an open community, so getting down voted by someone for your content(either a question or an answer) is not really that bad, its just an opinion and people are entitled to their opinions.
So better focus on improving your skills that worrying about down votes. :)

Hope to help. Let me know your thoughts on this.

Comment: The only problem is I can't think of why I would get a downvote. The answers, are, in my opinion, useful and correct, but I'm biased.

Comment: `I can't think of why I would get a downvote.`: The fact is that I don't get it either. So I guess its ok to get downvoted sometimes but also to make sure that your own answers or content makes sense.

Comment: " If there has been a down vote, it means that somebody felt the content was not worth putting up on Stack Overflow". Not necessarily. Could be tactical or personal.

Comment: Yes, the `tactical or personal` part is possible but I guess it wouldn't be worth the time it takes to figure out who down voted the content since the down voter's details are not shared. Thus, even if an answer or a question is down voted, it isn't really worth stressing over so much.

Comment: @DivijSehgal one downvote could mean that the answer is wrong. Regular downvotes on answers of a 10k user with no feedback whatsoever are highly unlikely to be due to technical reasons.

Comment: Also note that [in some cases, a downvote on an answer means that the DVer feels that the content of the _question_ isn't worth putting on SO, regardless of whether the answer itself is good](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255459/is-it-okay-to-downvote-answers-to-bad-questions).  While many users disagree, there are also users that believe [anyone who answers downvoted questions should be punished with downvotes](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252656/5386374), and there may be some that auto-downvote answers on downvoted questions to abuse a loophole in the Roomba & get the questions

Comment: deleted if no answer is accepted (I remember seeing a comment on meta that suspected there was a bot doing this, due to the poster seeing this behaviour on Meta as well (where there's no Roomba), but for the life of me, I can't find it).  This can sometimes explain strange downvotes that occur when the answer is accurate and useful, on the grounds that an answer to a useless question is in and of itself useless.

Comment: @JustinTime agreed. `This can sometimes explain strange downvotes that occur when the answer is accurate and useful, on the grounds that an answer to a useless question is in and of itself useless.` I totally agree on this part and I don't personally think an answer to a question that is useless in someone's opinion should be downvoted on the sole basis question seems not fit to be on SO or its affiliates. IMHO, if @ all, the basis for downvote should be if the content mentioned therein seems copied or unauthentic and irrelevant to the question in general.