# Is it OK to point out to a moderator suspected serial downvoting?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, serial-voting

A *certain user* has been downvoting a lot of perfectly good answers. I know this because I've seen their reputation go down point-by-point since yesterday, and I see no downvotes in the rep history.

I answer a lot of questions in the [Pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/pandas) tag, and so do a lot of others. Today and yesterday, on two different questions, several answers (by me and others) on both questions were downvoted, though they were perfectly good (and upvoted by me, FWIW).

The comments, if any, by this user are rather insulting as well. I flagged one of these comments as unfriendly or unkind and the flag was helpful and the comment was deleted.

Since these downvotes are not based on the quality of the post in the slightest bit, is it OK to tell a moderator about them? What should I do in this circumstance?

Comment: Somewhat, but unlike that question I believe I _do_ know who is doing the downvoting.

Comment: "Today and yesterday, on two different question, several answers (by me and others) on both questions were downvoted, though they were perfectly good (and upvoted by me, FWIW)." That's not serial voting. Serial voting is going through a specific user's posts and voting on them.

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of [Should I be concerned about some downvotes?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/344376/11682469) (tactical downvoting)

Comment: I can see this being taken to an extreme since playing detective on who is actually doing the voting is all based on circumstantial evidence. I have been accused many many times of casting votes that weren't mine when simply leaving a comment on something that was already down voted

Comment: I can see no serial downvoting on your profile. I don't think you have any reason for concern.

Comment: In addition to your account having no record whatsoever of targeted voting against it, the user you appear to be complaining about gave you a very specific reason for why they downvoted the answers: they were low-quality, code-only answers. By his standards, then, they were *not* "perfectly good answers", as you claim. That is a perfectly reasonable criteria on which to cast votes, and it is definitely voting on the content/quality of the posts, not the users.

Comment: A wild guess: Someone is fed up with the deluge of Pandas questions where some Pandas beginner states some particular data and wants to manipulate it in a certain (basic) way when the question should be have been closed as a duplicate of one of a relatively few canonical questions. And that someone wants to send a signal (by downvoting) to those answerers that should vote to close instead of answering the same basic beginner questions over and over and over again. (I know next to nothing about Pandas, but that is my impression.)

Comment: It is part of the tension between those that want to build a programming library that is easy to search and those that "just want to help". The former do not believe a Stack Overflow for beginners could work, but the presence of [the latter](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/371732/) (now deleted) proves that [it could work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390983).

Comment: @PeterMortensen I would argue that the presence of a portion of users just wanting a site to give and receive help does not prove that such a site could work. The answers in the question linked show multiple reasons why ([example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/390987)).

Comment: Here is a similar question for R (package "[dplyr](https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/pandoc/dplyr.html)", similar to Pandas) where the requirements are stated and Stack Overflow works as a script writing service (just like [Unix & Linux (Stack Exchange site)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)): *[Transforming a one-hot encoded variable to one column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70436830/)*

Comment: I'd like to note to everyone here, that I flagged this user for mod attention, and it was deleted the next day. A week or so later, they came back and DVed again, so I flagged them again, and a mod deleted them again. Haven't seen them since.

Comment: What is it that keeps this scheme going with the Pandas questions where just the requirements are stated along with some example data (work orders)? And answerers going along with it. [Paid homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417632/request-to-let-banned-users-ask-one-question-every-week#comment906279_417632)? Are they typical homework assignments? I can see it would be very easy for the instructors to vary the input data and slightly vary other things to those homework assignments in order to make cheating harder. [Recent example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6446053).

Comment: cont' - Even after having been a member of Stack Overflow for more than 5 years, there isn't any attempt to solve it by herself/himself. Just stated requirements (essentially work orders). Often it is 3-5 questions of this type the same day.

Comment: Perhaps even the answerers are in on the scheme as well? There is never an attempt to close the questions as duplicates or even comments about it. Perhaps Stack Overflow is just a convenient platform to exchange their services (the monetary exchange takes place elsewhere)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Flag something relevant - one of the downvoted answers - using the "other" option to raise your concerns and give as much information as you can in the flag so that the moderators can investigate.

We may determine that there's nothing that can be done - after all, the user may be thinking that all the answers are incorrect - but it's the best way to do this.

Comment: They might think the upvoted, accepted is incorrect? not too likely... but I'll do that.

Comment: If someone votes on all the answers to a question (and the answers are by different people), what is a moderator supposed to do or even should do? People are free to vote as they wish, unless they target someone with their votes (or in case of voting fraud, eg. sockpuppeting).

Comment: @user17242583 An upvoted and accepted answer might still be a bad answer. There is nothing unlikely about that. People vote and accept answers based on their opinions and the extent of their own understanding.

Comment: @JeanneDark If a user has answered a question and then downvotes all the other answers then that's targeting their votes. If they do it across several questions then - especially if it's a question with the same tags - that's targeting their votes.

Comment: What if the other answers are actually wrong? (They may be based on a misunderstanding of the question, for example.) Should one avoid voting on questions if you’ve answered them?

Comment: @BSMP - therein lies the difficulty. However, if there are no other downvotes on the answers or the answers are older (months or even years) then that's an *indication* there *may* be something going on.